# Term for something between "ephemeral" and "eternal"

Tags: word-request

There's no point googling this question, I discovered, because everything links to the ***difference** between* those two terms. I'd like to know what is the ***concept** between* instead.

If we have *never* and *always*, the in-between would be *sometimes* (possibly also *rarely* and *often*). If we have *newborn* and *elderly*, there's *adult* in-between.

What would be an appropriate term for *not-epheremal-and-not-eternal*?

Comment: *impermanent* or *temporary* come to mind, but in my experience it's not really a ternary spectrum - I could call anything that's not eternal *ephemeral*, whether it lasts a second or hundreds of years.

Comment: How about long-lasting, abiding, enduring, durable, semi-permanent, temporary, stable. I suppose the next question is what is the context?  How far along the line from ephemeral to eternal do you want to go?  There's a lot fo time in between!

Comment: @BillyKerr Your FUQ is highly appropriate. I didn't include it since I wanted to formulate a question with broad application. However, I see that the in-betweens may vary depending on the context. While still aspiring to a general set of alternatives, my specific case was creating the access passwords. Those are called *ephemeral* if lasting less than a day or *eternal* if exceeding a year (I know, I know but we change the certificate annually so it's eternal'ish). Then, we have this regular usage and I wished for a time-interval term instead like *lasting-quite-some-time-but-not-forever*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - then long-lasting would seem to be appropriate. No?

Comment: I'd say the *concept* here is ***permanence*** or ***durability***, but if you want to sound impressive, there's the relatively uncommon word [***perdurability***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/perdurability) to cover both shades of meaning.

Comment: @BillyKerr It would, in fact. I also had a discussion with a colleague and we're considering the term *periodic*. It's not quite along the scale between *ephemeral* and *eternal* but if you consider the specific use case (which you so adequately inquired about), then short-lived passwords and ever-lasting passwords will have the middle guy being periodically renewed passwords. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I prefer not to go for impressive because that's easy to overstep into pretentious, which is the last thing I'd like to be. However, *durable* is rather regular so it wouldn't be bad.

Comment: As it happens, in between posting my previous comment and this one, I've just been dealing with *my own* "special case". The context was me logged in to my brother's Linux Mint PC using "nomachine". I had to pick one of three choices as to how long the PC should *remember* the username and password I'd just typed in to access a SAMBA shared directory on another PC on his home network. The first and last options were 1 - *Forget immediately* and 3 - *Remember forever". I chose the middle option because I wasn't sure I was doing things right, but I forgot (or didn't read) exactly what it was...

Comment: ...consequently, I had to get my brother to reboot his PC and me reconnect remotely, so I could try to access the shared folder again, and see what the middle option was (I knew for sure it would forget after a reboot, *whatever* the middle option had specified). Turns out the middle option there was *[remember the connection credentials] **Until the user logs out*** - which *could* have been done without rebooting (log out and log back in again), but I didn't know that at the time!

Comment: if something is temporary, pending the implementation of something new, it's **transitional**.

Comment: While there are some single English words for intermediate states, if something is neither big nor small we say it is of *average height*, *intermediate height*, *medium height*, etc, and the same principle would apply here, e.g. *intermediate duration* (see also *medium term*).

Comment: Just as there's a wide range of terms between "newborn" and "elderly" (like: toddler, child, adolescent, teenager, young adult, adult, middle-aged, senior), there's also a wide range between "ephemeral" and "eternal". Please give us a context where someone might use this word.

Comment: @gotube It's been suggested by BillyKerr and addressed in the 3rd comment from above. Did you notice it? If so, is it insufficient and, hence, should be placed as a part of the main question text?